# Max in matrix with array

Tags: c++

I have written a program that find maximum element in each of matrix's row
But every time it has showed 57 , 58 , 52 , ... and just 50,....
I don't know how to fix it ... and I should just write it with array

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    
char mat[5][5];
    
cout << "Plaese enter Number in below Matrix element\t\t\n";
    
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    
    for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
        
    cout << "[" << row << "][" << column << "]\t:\t";

            cin >> mat[row][column];

        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    int max = 0;

    int row = 0;

    int column = 0;

    int col = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {

        for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {

            if (mat[row][column]>max) {

                max = mat[row][column];

                col = column;

            }

        }

        cout << "Max element in " << row << " is\t:\t" << max << " and its belong to " << mat[row][col];

        max = 0;



    }

    cin.get();

    cin.get();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: `max` and `col` are for maximum per the whole matrix, but you print intermediate results per row

Comment: Hi guys!Excuse me for answer your comments so late!Because , I don't have enough Internet to answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions lovely guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
char mat[5][5];
```

and looking for the maximum number. I would use

```
int mat[5][5];
```

I changed your code a little:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int mat[5][5];
    cout << "Plaese enter Number in below Matrix element\t\t\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {

        for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {

            cout << "[" << row << "][" << column << "]\t:\t";

            cin >> mat[row][column];

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int max = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
            if (mat[row][column] > max) {
                max = mat[row][column];
                col = column;
            }
        }
        cout << "Max element in " << row << " is\t:\t" << max << " and its belong to mat[" << row << "][" << col << "]"<< endl;
        max = 0;
    }
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

1. I changed the datatype of the matrix from char to int (this will allow entering 2 or more digits into the matrix.)
2. I changed the output of the result (You were outputting the values of the matrix thinking that the coordinates would be output)
3. I removed the declaration of variables that were re-declared

Comment: Hello ! Please excuse me for answer your comment so Late...I don't have enough Internet to answer ... Thank you for your suggestions so muuuuch*.*